# Is Refinery CMS ready for Rails 4 applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

We are trying to offer an all-around CMS with support for blogs and Spree to our clients. RefineryCMS seems like a good option, another being Alchemy. However, I've read in several places that Refinery doesn't go along very well with Rails 4. I've tried running an instance of it myself, but the only thing I could get working was with Rails 3.2, which is less than ideal for our organization, seeing as we use Rails 4. I was wondering, is RefineryCMS ready for Rails 4 production systems, or should we try our luck elsewhere? And if so, where would you suggest or would you suggest we roll our own systems?

Thanks for helping!

**Edit:** 
we have decided on using Comfortable Mexican Sofa and extend it to the point where it integrates with Spree and other apps through Devise. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refinery works with Rails 4, although it isn't available in rubygems (yet). You could reference the `master` branch of refinery : `https://github.com/refinery/refineryms` in your gem file as instructed [here](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2428).

Although, I would recommend locking down a commit which works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say it's production-ready? Because the way it seems right now, it's rather unstable...

Comment: It's been in this state for a while, it is being worked upon actively, hence my recommendation on locking down on a stable commit. I tried a few months ago, and it works ok, no major issues.

Answer (score 1):

We have faced a similar project like yours where our Rails app requires some sort of CMS for our client to update some pages.

After fiddling with Refinery, Comfortable-Mexican-Sofa, radiant and a few others, we decided to just write our own. This turns out to be pretty simple (as our client just need to update 2-3 static pages).

Our solution is to create a content/page model and then use Rails_Admin (Active Admins works too) to setup the backend for client to access. Each record on the content/page model simply correspond to a new page (Yes we have to hard-code the routes).

Not the best solution but it is faster than learning a new CMS framework and totally suitable for our project. Hope this sharing helps with your project!

Comment: Though I think integration with stuff like Spree might pose a problem then... And we would have to write our own blog system/integrate with another one. Any ideas on how to do the Spree integration?